# Json requests between c# and php file

Tags: c#, php, json

I want to send json request from c# to php file and save data into text file but php file can not read data
this is my code

```
User user = new User { id = 1, name = "Bob", address = "password", phone = "0111111111", activation = true };
                string json = "{\"id\":" + "\"" + user.id + "\""
                        + ",\"name\":" + "\"" + user.name + "\""
                        + ",\"address\":" + "\"" + user.address + "\""
                        + ",\"activation\":" + "\"" + user.activation + "\"}";

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8080/test.php");

                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.ContentLength = json.Length;

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                    streamWriter.Close();

                    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
```

and php file id

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$file = "LogFile.txt";
$handle = fopen($file, 'a') or die('ERROR: Cannot write to file: ' . $file);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');

fwrite($handle, $data); 
fclose($handle);
echo "SUCCESS";
```

?>

please what must i do in php file to read right? thank you

Comment: Is your `$data` empty. Any json errors? How do you think you are able to write object to file any way? You will find only `Object` or `Array` in your `LogFile.txt` making it this way

Comment: Oh, do not generate JSON manually using string concatenation.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev is right also, please refer to [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Answer (score 0):

This minimal piece of code was all I needed to solve my own problem:

```
$_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

if (isset($_data)) {
    $file = "users.txt";
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($_data));
}
```